# Overriding __eq__ and comparing two objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, initialization

I have two unique Temperature objects that I need to compare to each other, however, since the objects can be equal but have different units, I'm running into trouble comparing them.

For example

`t1 = Temperature(32.0, 'F')`

`t2 = Temperature(0.0, 'C')`

These two objects are equal, but I can't seem to get the correct implementation of `__eq__` to compare them

Here's what I have tried

```
class Temperature():

    def __init__(self, temp = 0.0, unit = 'C'):
        if float(temp) == str(temp):
            raise ValueError('could not convert string to float: ' + "'" + str(temp) + "'")
        else:
            self.t = float(temp)
        if unit.upper() not in 'CF':
            raise UnitError('Unrecognized temperature unit ' + "'" + str(unit) + "'")
        else:
            self.u = unit.upper()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Temperature({},'{}')".format(self.t, self.u)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.t) + '°' + self.u.upper()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        t1 = Temperature(self.t, self.u)
        t2 = Temperature(other.t, other.u)
        other.convert()

        if t1.t == t2.t and t1.u == t2.u:
            return True
        return False

    def convert(self):
        t = Temperature(self.t, self.u)
        if t.u.upper() == 'C':
            t.t *= 1.8
            t.t += 32
            t.u = 'F'
            return t
        else:
            t.t -= 32
            t.t /= 1.8
            t.u = 'C'
            return t
```

Notice that I do have a method to convert temperatures from one unit to another. Again, I can't seem to figure out how to compare the two objects, when they are in different units.

Comment: Just normalise when you compare

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm still somewhat new to Python, you'll have to expand a bit.

Comment: Watch out for floating-point rounding error.

Comment: You cannot presume that other is the only one you need to change, also you are likely to suffer from floating point limitations

Comment: When I deal with physical quantities, I always keep them in the same units in the program, and only convert when displaying them for the user.  IOW, I feel like associating a unit with the Temperature object is the Wrong Thing.  It's like saying integers should have some sort of attribute that says whether they print as hex or binary or decimal, and you need to consult such an attribute when comparing them.  My 2 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare the temperatures there is no need to always convert `other`. You only need to convert when `self` and `other` has different units. Once they are converted to same unit then temperature values can be compared.

Also you have returned new object from `convert()` method. So you need to assign the return value. And you should use the absolute value of the difference to avoid floating point errors.

This should work:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.u != other.u:
        other = other.convert()

    return math.fabs(self.t - other.t) < 1e-6
```

Comment: If the conversions are floating point then you need to allow for round off errors rather than requiring absolute equality

Comment: @sabbahillel thanks for pointing to that. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look too closely at your convert function, but assuming it correctly returns the convert temp, then this should work.  The basic idea is check if the units match.  If not, convert the other one and get its temp on the new scale.  If the units match, just compare the temps

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    other_temp = other.t
    if other.u != self.u:
        other_temp = other.convert().t

    if self.t == other_temp: #already ensured units match 
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Change both to one type and allow for floating point errors:

```
class Temperature():
    def __init__(self, temp=0.0, unit='C'):
        if float(temp) == str(temp):
            raise ValueError('could not convert string to float: ' + "'" + str(temp) + "'")
        else:
            self.t = float(temp)
        if unit.upper() not in 'CF':
            raise Exception
        else:
            self.u = unit.upper()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Temperature({},'{}')".format(self.t, self.u)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.t) + '°' + self.u.upper()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        t1, t1u = self.t, self.u
        t2, t2u = other.t, other.u
        other.convert()
        self.convert()

        equal = abs(self.t - other.t) < .0001
        self.t, self.u = t1, t1u
        other.t, other.u = t2, t2u
        return equal

    def convert(self):
        if self.u.upper() == 'C':
            self.t *= 1.8
            self.t += 32
            self.u = 'F'
```

You cannot just normalise one as you don't know which is fahrenheit or which is celsius, you need to presume that all variations are possible so just changing any celcius to fahrenheit will mean you always compare consistently:

```
In [6]: t1 = Temperature(100, "f")

In [7]: t2 = Temperature(37.7778, "c")

In [8]: t1 == t2
Out[8]: True

In [9]: t1.t
Out[9]: 100.0

In [10]: t2.t
Out[10]: 37.7778
```

You also don't want to change the actual attribute without being able to restore the values later, storing, converting, doing the comparison then resetting the attribute to the original values will mean the user gets back what the put in.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert to a standard unit - say you convert both fahrenheit and centigrade to Kelvin or always convert to Centigrade
2. Your converted values are floating
3. You allow for round off errors by using a limit value

For example Python (2.75)

```
import math
lim = 1e-8
if math.fabs(temp1 - temp2) > lim: # both have been converted
    print 'temperatures do not match
else:
    print 'temperatures match'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler to store the temperatures internally in a common unit, such as Kelvin.

```
def __init__(self, temp, unit):
    temp = float(temp)
    # Save the original input, perhaps for display purposes
    self.orig = temp
    self.unit = unit
    if unit == "K":
        self.t = temp
    elif unit == "C":
        self.t = tmp + 273.15
    elif unit == "F":
        self.t = (temp + 459.67) * 5 / 9.0
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unrecognized unit %s" % (unit,))
```

Then comparing any two `Temperature` is simply a matter of comparing their `t` attributes.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    try:
        return abs(self.t - other.t) < 1e-6  # Or some other tolerance
    else AttributeError:
        return False
        # or raise NotImplemented
```